# Uniform definition of $S(\mathbb{R})$ and $S(\mathbb{Q}_p)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, automorphic-forms

Let $\mathcal{P}=\{\infty, 2,3,5,7,11,\ldots\}$ be the set of primes of $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $\mathbb{Q}_p$ denote the corresponding completions, so in particular $\mathbb{Q}_{\infty}=\mathbb{R}$.

Is it possible to give a definition of the spaces of test functions $S(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ together with their standard topologies (finest locally convex for $p$ finite and usual Frechet in the real case) in a completely uniform way with respect to $p\in\mathcal{P}$?

It is not too hard to uniformly define $L^2(\mathbb{Q}_p, dx)$ as well as the Fourier transform as a unitary transformation on this space. The kind of definition I am looking for might look like:
$S(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is the smallest subspace of $L^2$ which is invariant by Fourier transform and... *insert mystery property here*...

Comment: I Guess because you are using the letter S you mean the schwartz space rather than test functions... In this case I would say "the largest subspace of $L^2$ stable under Fourier transform and multiplication by |x|". Also, from this perspective, the definition of the topology in the real case carry over to the p-adic space, I'm not exactly sure if it is the correct topology...

Comment: How does that force local constancy in the p-adic case?

Comment: You're right it does not work, but the following do: It is the largest subspace of $L^2$ stable under fourier transform, multiplication by $|x|$ and multiplication by locally constant functions.

Comment: I would like like answer where smoothness in the real case and local constancy in the p-adic case emerge a posteriori instead of being put in by hand in the definition.

Comment: Well, in the definition I gave you smoothness and local constancy do emerge a posteriori: the fact that you want something which is stable by multiplication by locally constant function does not implies directly that the function in the space should be them selve locally constant. But here is the problem: in the real case smoothness corresponds to quickly decreasing Fourier transform, while in the p-adique case local constancy corresponds to compactly supported Fourier transform, and unfortunately it is possible to define a notion of smoothness in the p-adic case: one can say...

Comment: I know, but what I am saying is if the expression "locally constant" occurs at all in the definition then I don't find the latter satisfactory. This sounds especially strange in the real special case since the requirement is vacuous for lack of locally constant functions.

Comment: ...say a function $f$ is smooth when its Fourrier transform is quickly decreasing, i.e. $|x|^k |\hat{f}(x)|$ is bounded for all $k$. And there is a p-adic schwartz space of quickly decreasing function with quickly decreasing fourier transform which is different from the classical schwartz space but ressemble a lot the the archimedian schwarz space.
It would help if you could explain why you want such a definition, for example the definition I gave you is uniform in the sense that I don't treat the p-adic and real case separately and I think can be applied directly to adelic frameworks.

Comment: my motivation comes from probability theory on the duals of these spaces. In the p-adic case I really want S' where S is the locally constant space not the one with rapid decay of f and its Fourier transform.

Comment: How about something like: subspace of $L^1\cap L^2$, stable under Fourier transform, _dense_ in $L^2$, and _nuclear_ (e.g., projective limit of Hilbert spaces with trace-class or Hilbert-Schmidt transition maps). Unclear whether one would have to add "minimal such"...

Comment: by nuclear you mean the more general definition of Grothendieck rather than countably Hilbert, right?

Comment: other issue with "subspace of $L^1\cap L^2$, Fourier stable, dense and nuclear": nuclearity with respect to which topology?

Answer (score 3):

François Bruhat in his [paper of 1961](https://eudml.org/doc/87007) (see page 61) gave a definition (and proved some properties) of the space ${\mathcal S}(G)$ of the Schwartz test functions on an arbitrary abelian locally compact group $G$.

Comment: yes but I find it a bit a cheat. As far as I know, Bruhat's description uses the rather heavy stucture theory of ALC groups and differentiability is put in by hand.

Comment: Your question is very vague... I can formulate a  hypothesis: perhaps ${\mathcal S}(G)$ is the subspace in $L_2(G)$ consisting of functions $f:G\to{\mathbb C}$ such that $f$ and its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ rest in $L_2$ after being multiplied by any polynomial $p$ (where a polynomial on $G$ is a linear combination of finite poducts of real characters, i.e. continuous homomorphisms $r:G\to{\mathbb R}$). I don't know, whether this is more intuitively reasonable (and whether this is true).

Comment: Yes, this seems to be true, if we change a bit the definition of a polynomial: $p$ must be *locally representable* as a finite linear combination of finite products of real characters.

Comment: why use multiplication by characters instead of $|x|$ as Simon is suggesting?

Comment: For any LCA-group $G$ the multiplication by a real character on $\widehat{G}$ corresponds to the differentiation over a one-parametric subgroup in $G$, that's why I am speaking about polynomials. I don't know whether the multiplication by $|x|^k$ gives the same class of functions, I don't have intuition in $p$-adic fields.