# Relationship between Harish-Chandra Schwartz space and more generic Schwartz spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis

If $G$ is a connected semisimple Lie group with finite center, Harish-Chandra defined a Schwartz space of rapidly decreasing functions on $G$ as the space of $\mathrm{C}^\infty$ functions defined by the seminorms

$$\|f\|_{D_1, D_2, r} = \sup_{g \in G} \frac{(1 + \sigma(g))^r |f(D_1 ; g ; D_2)|}{\Xi(g)}$$

where $D_1$ and $D_2$ are left and right-invariant differential operators on $G$ respectively, $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $D_1 ; g ; D_2$ is the two-sided action of $D_1$ and $D_2$ on $g$, and $\sigma$ and $\Xi$ are the standard functions defined by Harish-Chandra.

An arguably more intuitive definition of rapidly decreasing function that matches the use in other contexts would be the space of $f \in \mathrm{C}^\infty$ defined by the seminorms

$$\|f\|_P = \sup_{g \in G} |P f(g)|$$

for every polynomial $P$ in one-sided-invariant differential operators on $G$.

What is the relationship between these two definitions of rapidly decreasing function? Why is it necessary to use a more particular definition of Schwartz space for semisimple Lie groups? There doesn't appear to be anything stopping one from turning the latter definition into a usable convolution algebra.

Comment: check the book of Wallach Real reductive groups I,

Answer (score 2):

Belatedly...

I think this is a very reasonable question, if only for the implicit question "what would characterize a 'correct' Schwartz space?"

Yes, from one side, as in the question, something about rapid decay of derivatives... In Harish-Chandra's presentation, there is a specific gauge of "rate of growth", with functions naturally arising from the repn theory.

And, then, since H-C proved several theorems about things that were harmonious with his defn of "Schwartz" functions, in that regard his definition is "correct".

But, still, a feature that is a bit fancier, but is very useful, is that a "good" notion of "Schwartz space" on a smooth manifold should include its nuclearity, meaning (for me) that it admits tensor products with similar TVS's. The simplest case of "nuclearity" is as a countable (projective) limit of Hilbert spaces, with Hilbert-Schmidt transition maps. Pairs of such things admit genuine-categorical tensor products! Explicitly,
$$
(\lim_n X_n) \otimes_{categorical} (\lim_n Y_n) 
=\lim_n (X_n\otimes_{HS} Y_n)
$$
where $\otimes_{HS}$ is the Hilbert-Schmidt norm completion of the algebraic tensor product. The existence of a genuine tensor product gives the Hom-tensor adjunction, also known as the Cartan-Eilenberg adjunction, which gives a one-line proof of (most of) a Schwartz Kernel Theorem, for example.

I myself have *not* carried out any verification of the nuclearity of H-C's "Schwartz space". Casselman's notes on such things explicitly disaver such verification, also. Possibly someone has done this, or can give a pointer, but I cannot, even after a modest effort. :)

Comment: +1. I think this is an important question and I asked a related one here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217663/uniform-definition-of-s-mathbbr-and-s-mathbbq-p I also agree that a definition is "correct" if it is the hypothesis of lots of nice theorems. But it is also worthwhile to find an equivalent formulation of the "correct" definition which is also conceptually "natural" and does not appear contrived or the result of some clever construction. Another definition I know for $\mathbb{R}^n$, the original one by Schwartz, is roughly $(S')'$ where $S'$ is the subspace...

Comment: ...of $D'$ made of restrictions of distribution which live on the $n$-dimensional sphere obtained by adding the point at infinity. I was wondering if something similar works for Lie groups. Is there some natural compactification analogous to the sphere for $\mathbb{R}^n$ which would produce the correct Schwartz space in a similar manner.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, yes, this "geometric" characterization of Schwartz space is useful... but/and it does depend on the _metrical_ properties of the compactification, and the fact (for $\mathbb R^n$) that there's a handy _smooth_ one-point compactification, etc. A linear reductive Lie group (I know, sometimes the linearity is part of the defn of "reductive"...) could be viewed as a sub-thing of the analogous one-point compactification of the ambient $\mathbb R^{n^2}$, but I don't think it'd be nice at infinity. Maybe that doesn't matter?

Comment: Yes I expect this is not a straightforward thing to do, and could e.g. need Hironaka's resolution of singularities or something of this kind. I know there is work by Aizenbud and Gurevitch on this kind of, and even more general, Schwartz spaces, in the context of the Langlands program (which you know a lot about, and definitely much more than me).