# Interpretation of $p$-adic 'smoothness'

Tags: rt.representation-theory, terminology, p-adic-analysis, smoothness, p-adic

**real case:** In the very first course of Calculus, one learns that a real function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is called **smooth**, if it is differentiable as many times as one pleases. So the intuitive idea behind 'smoothness' is that the graph of $f$ is, well... smooth if you look at it.

**p-adic case:**
Now the picture changes in the $p$-adics; one sets **smooth** := 'invariant w.r.t. an open subset', for example in representation theory (of let's say $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ of a local field $K$), and one can show that
**smooth** = **locally constant** + **compact support**. I always took this as the definition. I also always assumed (and maybe I also heard or read) that one uses the word smooth in the $p$-adic setting, s.t. one can put things into a more general setting just by referring to smooth functions $K \to \mathbb{C}$ for whatever field $K \in \{\mathbb{Q}_p, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}_{p \text{ prime}}$ is.

**For example**, one defines the space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ of (Bruhat)-Schwartz functions as the space of smooth functions $\mathbb{Q}_p \to \mathbb{C}$, and one has a (very) similar definition for $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ (as smooth + rapidly decreasing derivatives). This might not be the best example but it surely reflects a little what I tried to tell.

But I am kind of not satisfied with the motivation for the definition. So my question is...

**Question:**
Is there some deeper analogy with the real in the sense of maybe the $p$-adic differentiation? Or maybe generalizing the question.. I would really like to see some 'intuition' or rather 'motivation' behind the definition, so that I can say, "OK, this is really the right word for smoothness in the $p$-adic case".

Comment: Have you seen for instance [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Schwartz-Bruhat+function) on Bruhat-Schwartz functions?

Comment: Hi Wojowu. Thanks for your comment, but it somehow misses my question.

Comment: Does it completely though? It gives a definition for general locally compact abelian group, by writing the group as an inverse limit of Lie groups and taking spaces of smooth functions on those. For (locally) profinite groups this happens to trivialize, since they are written as inverse limits of 0-dimensional manifolds, but it still fits into the same framework.

Comment: Well, this is the definition of Bruhat-Schwartz functions. My question regards rather the motivation for $p$-adic 'smoothness' to define it the way it is defined.

Comment: Functions $\mathbf Q_p \to \mathbf C$, or $\mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf C$, are kind of strange things, don't you think?  We're not going to be able to describe them using power series since $\mathbf Q_p$ and $\mathbf Z_p$ have no reasonable embedding into $\mathbf C$ that respects the algebra and topology (sure, there are embeddings algebraically by Zorn's lemma, but not in any natural way).  So locally constant + compact support for complex-valued functions on the $p$-adics is about all we can think of as an analogue of the smooth + rapid decay definition for Schwartz functions.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that there are many continuous characters $\mathbf Q_p \to S^1$ and $\mathbf Z_p \to S^1$ when you do Fourier analysis on these locally compact abelian groups. And such continuous characters have a property that reflects their $p$-adic domains: they must be locally constant. That's because $\mathbf Q_p$ and $\mathbf Z_p$ have arbitrarily small open subgroups around $0$, while $S^1$ has "no small subgroups" (the only subgroup in a small nbd. of 1 is $\{1\}$), and that forces each group hom $\mathbf Z_p \to S^1$ to be trivial on $p^N\mathbf Z_p$ for large $N$.

Comment: Hi KConrad, thank you for your reply. So if I understood you correctly, 'smoothness' is the abstraction of (and thus has its motivation in) the properties of a local character $\chi \colon \mathbb{Q}_p \to S^{1}$?
btw are you the famous KConrad? Your notes are par excellance!

Comment: I thought smooth only meant locally constant. Where does the compact support condition come from?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam  it comes from seeking analogues on $p$-adic domains of classical Schwartz spaces: complex-valued functions on $p$-adic domains of rapid decay with all derivatives. There are no useful nonvanishing functions $\mathbf Q_p \to \mathbf C$ with rapid decay, and such functions have no derivatives, so the analogue of "rapid decay " is taken to be "compact support". For example, the characteristic function of $\mathbf Z_p$ is such a function.  The role of locally constant functions with compact support in, for instance, Tate's thesis, shows such functions are worthwhile to use.

Comment: @KConrad: yes I know all this, I have written research papers on these matters. My question was not why compact support is natural a substitute in the p-adic context for the notion of rapid decay. It was why include it in the package of being smooth? For example I and coauthors constructed random distributions in $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{Q}_p^3)$ inspired by QFT. The moments of such objects are smooth on the complement of the diagonal but not compactly supported. It's a bit like $1/|x|_p$ on $\mathbb{Q}_p\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: @KConrad: since we're at it, I would be interested in your thoughts on this old MO question of mine https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217663/uniform-definition-of-s-mathbbr-and-s-mathbbq-p

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I agree that the usual definition of spaces of complex-valued functions in the non-archimedean context looks awkward: it is imposed by analogy to the archimedean case, rather than by a unified description (unlike unified concepts such as valued fields & locally compact groups). And approaches that aim to be unified need hard structure theorems. It's an unfortunate situation. Maybe it was a mistake to use "smooth" in p-adic settings for "locally constant + compact support" but now we're stuck with it. In motivating examples, loc. constant with non-cpt support never arose.

Comment: Just like on $\mathbb{R}$, some distributions may be smooth near some points and singular at some other points, hence a notion of singular support. One may define a space $\mathscr{E}(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ of functions which are locally constant with no condition on the support. This should give a multiplier space for both the space of test functions $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and the space of distributions $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. Yes it was a mistake to misuse "smooth" and it's not too late to fix it.

Comment: The "mistake" was perhaps made by analysts instead of number theorists, and may come from the definition of smooth vectors in a Hilbert space for an unbounded operator like the oscillator $|\xi|^2+|x|^2$ Hamiltonian.